# Where and how catch gsutil errors on during deployment of my website?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, continuous-deployment

I have a personal website hosted on Google Cloud storage. The way I am deploying my website on my bucket is the following:

- Github Actions runs `make deploy` when I am pushing on the branch develop
- Make deploy is running a shell script called `bin/deploy.sh`

I have a billing issue on my Google Cloud account so i am not able to modify anything on my GCS bucket. In fact, If I run make deploy locally, I am getting this error log:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with a delinquent billing account.
CommandException: 29 files/objects could not be copied/removed.
make: *** No rule to make target `do', needed by `deploy'.  Stop.
```

My Github Actions pipeline succeeded and did not report any error.
[image]

When and how should I catch a gcloud error?

**deploy.sh**

```
# set website config
gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://pierre-alexandre.io

# add user permissions
gsutil iam ch allUsers:legacyObjectReader gs://pierre-alexandre.io

# copy the website files!
gsutil -m rsync -d -r public_html gs://pierre-alexandre.io
```

**Makefile**

```
deploy: $(shell ./bin/deploy.sh)
```

**.github/workflows/main.yml**

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Deployment to production server 
        run: |
          echo deploying new version on pierre-alexandre.io ...
          echo make deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what @Mousumi provided, please find an example of how you can catch gstil errors, by writing some [shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47058051/16313960).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to your account being suspended. To reinstate the billing account is to update the payment method and settle the outstanding balance and reopen the account so you may use the project link in it.

To update the payment method, kindly refer to the steps on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#update_your_payment_method).

To reopen the billing account, kindly refer to the steps on this [page](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#reopen_a_closed_billing_account).