# Google Cloud Storage Unable to create your folder. Try again of contact you administrator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I use google cloud storage to store static data. at the start of the build I was able to create the folder without any problems. some time ago I wanted to create a new folder on my cloud storage and an error appeared as below:

[image]

Even though as I recall, I didn't make any changes before, at that time I was able to create folders and now why can't I create folders?

[image]

I've tried adding my email to cloud storage permissions with the role as storage admin and storage legacy bucket owner in the hope of creating a folder. but when I save the configuration and try to create the folder again, the same error still appears and still can't create the folder. but if uploading files to cloud storage is not a problem, the files can be uploaded properly. But why can't I create a folder.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what happens if you run this gsutil cp existingfile gs://bucketname/folderyouwant/     hopefully you can get a more meaningful error + it should create folder folderyouwant. Try in cloudshell

Comment: If i run the command above i got this error:  `AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with a delinquent billing account`.

Comment: Looks like a billing issue. I believe you can chat with billing at Menu

Comment: Check answer here from Mousoumi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69871639/where-and-how-catch-gsutil-errors-on-during-deployment-of-my-website

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments and the linked question, you cannot create new buckets due to having a delinquent billing account. You can reactivate it by following [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#reopen_a_closed_billing_account). Keep in mind that you will need the required permissions and resolve any delayed/declined payments. You can also contact the [Billing team](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing).